# Justification for Statements on Beam Deflection

Tags: material-science, elasticity

I am teaching students at a high school about bending of a beam (the beam is clamped at one end and then an applied force acts downwards close to the end of the beam to bend it).

I thought that it did not require further explanation that the deflection of the beam due to the force at the end is inversely proportional to the stiffness of the beam, proportional to the size of the applied force, and that it is dependent on the distance from the fixed point where the beam is clamped.

However, I have been asked to provide justification for these statements and not to appeal to physical intuition which is not obvious to students who are not seasoned physicists.  What type of justification would be enough to use these statements at an elementary level?  How could I explain that these statements are true?

Comment: Did you give them the max deflection equation $$\delta =\frac{FL^3}{3EI}$$

Comment: Where does that equation comes from though?  Seems like you would have to use Euler-Bernoulli theory which I am trying to avoid for now.

Comment: The derivation isn’t simple. But the equation supports your intuitive explanation

Comment: That's one possibility, is there another way to support my explanation without using this?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you’re looking for. It seems any non mathematical explanation would again involve intuition.  Sorry I couldn’t be of help

Comment: Actually, if I were teaching the class I would present the equation and use some physical examples to connect it with intuition. As an example I would compare the bending of say a plastic straw and a pencil fixed at one end with some weight initially hanging on the other end. The straw will bend but the pencil won't (or maybe only slightly) because the pencil is much more stiff (higher E).

Comment: Put a larger weight on the straw and it bends more (because F is higher). Move the weight closer to the supported end of the straw and it bends less (because L is less).  The effect of moment of inertia (I) would be more difficult to demonstrate.

Comment: Why bother teaching students about beam bending if you’re not going to give them the deflection formula? Not every formula needs to be derived from first principles.